# how to make an interactive UI when a huge process is running in the background in Universal windows platform?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

Currently am working on a project in clean architecture. I want to make an interactive UI even a huge process is running in backend.

```
  private async void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (addFriendsViewModel.isValidMailId(mailId.Text))
        {
          isFriendAddedSuccessfully = await 
          addFriendsViewModel.AddUserInDB(mailId.Text);

            if (isFriendAddedSuccessfully)
                showSuccessDialog();
            else
                showErrorDialog();
        }
     }
```

this is my click event listener.

```
 public async Task<bool> AddUserInDB(string friendMailId)
    { 
        if (isValidUser(friendMailId) && !isAlreadyFriends())
        {
           addFriendUseCase = new AddFriendsUseCase(new FriendsDetail() {   
                             friendsUserId = friendsUserId ,userID = 1 });
            addFriendUseCase.SetCallBack<AddFriendCallBack>(this);
            for(int i=1;i<1000000000;i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("hi there" + i);
            }
            addFriendUseCase.Execute();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

in the above code the for loop is the sample huge process.

I want make the interactive UI even that huge process(for loop) is running.
but currenty my ui is not interactive when the control reaches that.

Comment: Are you saying `isFriendAddedSuccessfully = await 
          addFriendsViewModel.AddUserInDB(mailId.Text);` does not immediately returns to caller? Can you debug to check that?

Comment: i want to make an interactive ui and am a beginner to uwp so i don't know the proper way to do that.

Comment: try `isFriendAddedSuccessfully = await 
          addFriendsViewModel.AddUserInDB(mailId.Text).ConfigureAwait(false);`. Also [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/) will help you

Comment: A long running CPU intensive task should not be performed on the UI thread. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188475/backgroundworker-vs-async-await has some interesting answers that should help you sort out your confusingly mixed use of TAP and APM . Your existing solution jams the UI because it doesn't actually have anything awaitable nor does it await anything so it just runs synchronously and you're probably seeing compiler warnings to this effect

Comment: There is nothing async about your call, just because you can put the async keyword on a method does not make it async. please read up on the async and await pattern. Also consider awaiting a Task.Run for your cpu bound workload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you mark a method `async` doesn't actually make it run asynchronously on another thread per-se - this is a common misconception about `async/await`. In fact, the `async/await` functionality works in such a way the code keeps executing on the same thread up until the point where it encounters a "real" async call - this could be a I/O bound `await` operation for example (files, networking etc.). And immediately after this I/O operation it once again returns to the original thread (unless `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used). In your case, the method does not contain any `await` at all so it will run completely on the UI thread and only return after it is finished.

If you want to run the operation on another thread, you can use `Task.Run`:

```
await Task.Run(()=> DoSomething());
```

This will not make your UI show progress updates directly, but it will stay responsive while the operation is running. If you want to show progress updates, you should implement the operation in a class with an `event` that will report progress and subscribe to it. You would however need to make sure to run the event handler on the UI thread again - using `Dispatcher`. For example check [this blog post](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2016/01/20/awaiting-the-coredispatcher/) for more details.

Comment: `await Task.Run(()=> DoSomething());`  throws the **The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread**  Exception

Comment: Yes, this happens if you attempt to work with UI elements from a non-UI thread. You must wrap UI manipulation into `Dispatcher` as I mentioned at the end of the answer. Please update the question with current code if possible, so I can help better.